# How to join streams based on a key

Tags: rxjs, redux-observable

This is for `redux-observable` but I think the general pattern is pretty generic to `rxjs`

I have a stream of events (from `redux-observable`, these are redux actions) and I'm specifically looking to pair up two differnt types of events for the same "resource" - "resource set active" and "resource loaded" - and emit a new event when these events "match up". The problem is these can come in in any order, for any resources, and can be fired multiple times. You might set something active before it is loaded, or load something before it is set active, and other resources might get loaded or set active in between.

What I want is a stream of "this resource, which is now loaded, is now active" - which also means that once a resource is loaded, it can be considered forever loaded.

If these events were not keyed by a resource id, then it would be very simple:

First I would split them up by type:

```
const setActive$ = action$.filter(a => a.type == 'set_active');
const load = action$.filter(a => a.type == 'loaded');
```

In a simple case where there is no keying, I'd say something like:

```
const readyevent$ = setActive$.withLatestFrom(loaded$)
```

then `readyevent$` is just a stream of `set_active` events where there has been at least one `loaded` event.

But my problem is that the `set_active` and `loaded` events are each keyed by a resource id, and for reasons beyond my control, the property to identify the resource is different in the two events. So this becomes something like:

```
const setActive$ = action$.filter(a => a.type === 'set_active').groupBy(a => a.activeResourceId);
const loaded$ = action$.filter(a => a.type === 'loaded').groupBy(a => a.id);
```

but from this point I can't really figure out how to then "re-join
" these two streams-of-grouped-observables on the same key, so that I can emit a stream of `withLatestFrom` actions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this does what you are describing:

```js
const action$ = Rx.Observable.from([
  { activeResourceId: 1, type: 'set_active' },
  { id: 2, type: 'loaded' },
  { id: 1, type: 'random' },
  { id: 1, type: 'loaded' },
  { activeResourceId: 2, type: 'set_active' }
]).zip(
  Rx.Observable.interval(500),
  (x) => x
).do((x) => { console.log('action', x); }).share();

const setActiveAction$ = action$.filter(a => a.type === 'set_active')
  .map(a => a.activeResourceId)
  .distinct();
const allActive$ = setActiveAction$.scan((acc, curr) => [...acc, curr], []);
  
const loadedAction$ = action$.filter(a => a.type === 'loaded')
  .map(a => a.id)
  .distinct();
const allLoaded$ = loadedAction$.scan((acc, curr) => [...acc, curr], []);
  
Rx.Observable.merge(
  setActiveAction$
    .withLatestFrom(allLoaded$)
    .filter(([activeId, loaded]) => loaded.includes(activeId)),
  loadedAction$
    .withLatestFrom(allActive$)
    .filter(([loadedId, active]) => active.includes(loadedId))
).map(([id]) => id)
 .distinct()
 .subscribe((id) => { console.log(`${id} is loaded and active`); });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/5.5.10/Rx.min.js"></script>
```

The basic approach is to create a distinct stream for each action type and join it with the distinct aggregate of the other. Then merge the two streams. This will emit the value when there are matching setActive and loaded events. The `distinct()` on the end of the merge makes it so that you will only get notified once. If you want a notification on each setActive action after the initial one then just remove that operator.

Comment: This is mostly what I was expecting, thanks! I didn't think to transform the objects of one type (action objects) to another type (the id) and then tease them back apart.

I was hoping not to have to maintain my own state of loaded projects (since that also appears in `getState()` but it doesn't look like there's any other generalizable way to do that.

Comment: @alecf what do you mean by `also appears in getState()`?

Comment: sorry also appears in the state - in the case of using this for redux-observable, the state already maintains which resources are loaded...

Comment: You could just do `setActiveAction$.withLatestFrom(store.select(x => x.loaded))` instead.

Comment: The problem here is that the actions are effectively keyed by resource I'd, so the setActives from one resource have to be paired up with the loads for that same resource I'd, not any random resource key

Comment: @alecf I wasn't suggesting to remove the filter but to rather use your store instead of creating a `loadedAction$` stream.

Answer (score 0):

`groupBy` looks somewhat complicated to do this with, there's a key value in there but you get an Observable of Observables - so maybe a little hard to get right.

I would map the id to a common property and then use **scan** to combine. I use this pattern for grouping in my app.

The accumulator in the scan is an object, which is used as an associative array - each property is an id and the property value is an array of actions accumulated so far.

After the scan, we convert to an observable stream of arrays of matching actions - sort of like `withLatestFrom` but some arrays may not yet be complete.

The next step is to filter for those arrays we consider complete.
Since you say

> where there has been at least one loaded event

I'm going to assume that the presence of two or more actions, with at least one is type 'loaded' - but it's a bit tricky to tell from your question if that is sufficient.

Finally, reset that id in the accumulator as presumably it may occur again later in the stream.

```js
const setActive$ = action$.filter(a => a.type === 'set_active')
  .map(a => { return { id: a.activeResourceId, action: a } });

const loaded$ = action$.filter(a => a.type === 'loaded')
  .map(a => { return { id: a.id, action: a } });

const accumulator = {};
const readyevent$: Observable<action[]> = 
  Observable.merge(setActive$, loaded$)
  .scan((acc, curr) => {
    acc[curr.id] = acc[curr.id] || [];
    acc[curr.id].push(curr.action)
  }, accumulator)
  .mergeMap((grouped: {}) => Observable.from(
    Object.keys(grouped).map(key => grouped[key])
  ))
  .filter((actions: action[]) => {
    return actions.length > 1 && actions.some(a => a.type === 'loaded')
   })
  .do(actions => {
    const id = actions.find(a => a.type === 'loaded').id;
    accumulator[id] = [];
  });
```